# I have to replace the values in column using multiple functions in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter

IgnitionStatus = 0,1,2,3,4,5
ActMod_trqCrS_f = 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7

df1[ (df1['IgnitionStatus'] ==0) & (df1['ActMod_trqCrS_f'] != 0) ]

if the above conditions satisfy then I have to replace it by zero.

How to do it ?

Comment: df1.replace( df1[ (df1['IgnitionStatus'] ==0) & (df1['ActMod_trqCrS_f'] != 0)], 0 , inplace = True )
This doesn't work, what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use the function `where` from numpy.
For example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'IgnitionStatus': np.arange(8),
                    'ActMod_trqCrS_f': np.arange(8)
})
criteria = (df1['IgnitionStatus'] ==3) & (df1['ActMod_trqCrS_f'] != 0) 
df1['ActMod_trqCrS_f'] = np.where(criteria, 0, df1['ActMod_trqCrS_f'])
display(df1)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEjtd.png)